# Is there a way to increment after a for-loop using enumerate in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to have a starting number that increments by 10 each iteration using for-loop enumerate on Python3. I have to use enumerate because of the code before, I use append to get the right format I want. I also had a nested for loop before the code I displayed further down to look like a multiplication table. **Is there another way I can make a multiplication table show below so I don't have to worry about enumerate?**

I have already tried the multiplication iteration using the nested for loop. My instructor wants me to format it like how I had it above. My indentations are wrong. I used arrays to append. I already have the table working but I want the row to start at 100 and increment by 10 each time. Instead, it starts from 100 and goes up by 1.

```
for display_table, row in enumerate(rows, 100):
    print('{0:>3}\t{1}'.format(display_table, ''.join(row)))

         58      60      62      64      66      68          
100     20.9    19.5    18.3    17.2    16.1    15.2     
101     23.0    21.5    20.1    18.9    17.8    16.7      
102
103
104
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for display_table, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    print('{0:>3}\t{1}'.format(display_table*100, ''.join(row)))
```

Have you considered changing your code like the above?

Comment: you meant display_table*10 instead of display_table*100? because OP wants to increment it by 10

Comment: I think print('{0:>3}\t{1}'.format(100+display_table*10, ''.join(row))) will solve this.

Comment: THAT SOLVED IT THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps consider `zip`ing together your rows and a generator of tens?

```
import itertools

tens = itertools.count(10, step=10)  # generates: 10 20 30 40 50 60 ...

for row_name, row in zip(tens, rows):
    ...
```